# Tomcat 9 with Apache 2.4 Proxy: 408 after correct login

Tags: apache, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I'm running Apache 2.4 as Reverse Proxy in front of Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 18.04.

The Tomcat application is deployed in /apachetest and is using form-based authentification.

When calling "http://10.10.50.20/apachetest"  (without proxy)

- the login-page is comming up
- I put in the credentials
- and than "index.html" is delivered

So far ...

On Apache I have configured a virtual host for ssl:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8087/apachetest/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8087/apachetest/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /apachetest
```

when calling https://apachetest.localdomain/
- the login-page is comming up
 - I put in the credentials
 - and than I receive "**HTTP Status 408 – Request Timeout**" from Tomcat

By using the developer tools of Chrome I can see the following header for request "j_security_check"

General:
- Request URL: https://apachetest.localdomain/j_security_check
- Request Method: POST
- Status Code: 408
- Remote Address: 10.10.50.20:443
- Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Header

Connection: close
- Content-Language: de
- Content-Length: 1239
- Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
- Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 10:36:28 GMT
- Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
- X-Frame-Options: DENY

Request Header:
-Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
- Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
- Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
- Cache-Control: max-age=0
- Connection: keep-alive
- Content-Length: 43
- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Cookie: JSESSIONID=B859EE1F208D4D1C26C7B5714A41B03D
- Host: apachetest.localdomain
- Origin: https://apachetest.localdomain
- Referer: https://apachetest.localdomain/
- Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
- Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
- Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36

Comment: I don't think it's quite clear what you are asking for, please provide more detail on what the problem is and what result you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest in my question.

ok, I will try again.

I'm looking for a configuration to have a Tomcat Web-Application running behind an Apache Reverse Proxy.

The Tomcat Web-Application have a form-based authentification implemented.

By calling the Tomcat Web-Application, through proxy, I get the expected login-page.
But after putting in the right credentials and submit, I receive the following message:
"HTTP Status 408 – Request Timeout".

The expected site "index.html" is not provided.